# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIBarButtonSystemItem' to different enumeration type 'UIBarButtonItemStyle' - iPad - iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sdk

I am getting the warning in the subject line above when running my app under xCode 4.3.

Here is the offending code :

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:map];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(removeCurrent)];
    map.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Can anyone help ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` should be `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`. System item is used in a different init method - `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:` - which may actually be better for you as it will return a localised done button rather than the fixed text you have now.

Comment: put this links to answer for completion. [style must be One of the constants defined in UIBarButtonItemStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)     AND       [UIBarButtonItemStyle typedef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)